# Can I rewrite this query without union clause

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a `sliders` table. It is something that looks like this:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | video_url | image_url |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | null      | imgurl1   |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 2  | null      | imgurl2   |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 3  | null      | imgurl3   |
+----+-----------+-----------+
| 4  | vidurl1   | null      |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

I can achieve what I want using this query:

```
(SELECT * FROM sliders WHERE image_url IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM sliders WHERE video_url IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM sliders)
```

**Basically, the order I want is:**

1. First Image
2. First Video
3. ...
4. Everything else

So based on the example, the result should be **(based on the id) is [1,4,2,3]**.

Is this possible to recreate without using `UNION` clause?

By the way, I am using Ruby on Rails on this project and currently using `find_by_sql` to execute the query. If you can help me use `ActiveRecord` instead, that would be great.

As of now, I can't see a way to union tables when using ActiveRecord.

Comment: Why are you doing pure SQL queries ? Do you have models ? Also having empty values is not a good practice... Why don't you have a `sliders` model with `videos` and `images` being children models of `sliders`. So let's say you want the first slider, you can reach first image and first video this way : `Slider.first.images.first` and `Slider.first.videos.first` ... or collect all images `Slider.first.images.all` and then give a special treatment of the first image in your view ...

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "first" record in a SQL table.  Your subqueries don't have `order by`, so this returns *indeterminate* rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is no solution for the problem given. A query result is only then guaranteed to be sorted when you apply `ORDER BY`, which you don't. Your query boils down to a mere

```
SELECT * FROM sliders;
```

Even if you happen to get the rows in the desired order with your query now, this can be already different the next time you run it.

(Apart from this, you are applying `LIMIT 1` without an `ORDER BY` clause, which just picks a record arbitrarily. You could get any of the image urls with the first subquery.)

You need an `ORDER BY` clause in which you must check whether the row's ID is the first image or the first video:

```
SELECT *
FROM sliders
ORDER BY
  id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM sliders WHERE image_url IS NOT NULL) DESC,
  id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM sliders WHERE video_url IS NOT NULL) DESC,
  id;
```

(This makes use of MySQL's true = 1, false = 0. By sorting in descending order, we get true before false.)

Answer (score 1):

One method in MySQL is to use variables:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             (case when image_url is not null then @rn_i := @rn_i + 1 end) as rn_i,
             (case when video_url is not null then @rn_v := @rn_v + 1 end) as rn_v,
      from sliders cross join
           (select @rn_i := 0, @rn_v := 0) params
      order by id
     ) s
order by (rn_i = 1) desc, (rn_v = 1) desc, id asc;
```